# saving variable values after execution stops

Tags: c#, arcgis

I am developing a vc# app using arcgis runtime sdk. For data types like int string etc. I would store variable values in txt file n then access it using parse or tostring method. But the variables that the arcgis sdk provides i can store the value but then cant assign it after rerunning the program. Any suggestions??

Comment: can you please add some code?

Comment: this is an example of var whose val I want saved after execution stops         
Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.Geometry poly1 = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.Geometry();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the classes have methods to convert to/from JSON.

[Geometry.ToJson Method](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/store/api-reference/html/M_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_Geometry_ToJson.htm)
[Geometry.FromJson Method](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/store/api-reference/html/M_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_Geometry_FromJson.htm)

So instead of `ToString` and `Parse` functions, use the `ToJson` and `FromJson` to store and load the values from a file (`ToJson` returns a JSON formatted string for an object, and `FromJson` takes a JSON formatted string to generate an object).

For reference: [JSON](http://json.org/)